# New branch from Git Stash will affect other stashes?

Tags: git, git-stash

I have the master branch on which I stashed multiple changes and now I want to create a new branch from the stashed changes which are at {0}. But I doubt that creation of the new branch will not affect my other stashes, because `git` will drop my stash after creation of the new branch. Will `git` only drop stashes at {0} index or will it drop all of the stashes? The stashed changes are too IMP for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer** : No worries, stash entries are independent from one another. Go for it.

---

**Longer answer** : (with a visual example)

To help picture it, the stash can be viewed as a list of unrelated commits, each pointing to different points in the repo tree.

See on the **Hypothetical situation** below

```
        F---G <<< feature/abc
       /
      /           H---I <<< bugfix/123
     /           /     \
A---B---C---D---E---F---J <<< master
         \
          \
           K---L---M <<< feature/xyz
```

and the following **Hypothetical scenario**

You stashed changes a number of times during the last couple of days, while you were working on these different branches.

Let's say you stashed three times :

- once on `feature/abc` during your first attempt at committing `G` because you were unsatisfied with your first approach altogether but wanted to keep it at hand just in case.
- then you were interrupted while working on the bugfix/123, a bit after having committed `H`, and had to switch branches. Later you came back to `bugfix/123` then did a `git stash apply` rather than `git stash pop` to keep the entry alive in the stash for later reuse/inspection.

and finally

- had to stash again after `L` while working on `feature/xyz`

(The operations happened in that order.)

**Resulting stash situation**

At this point your stash list would look like

```
stash@{0}: WIP on feature/xyz: f1d6b3a unfinished - get rid of var dumps
stash@{1}: WIP on hotfix/123: 94722ae unfinished - css still broken
stash@{2}: WIP on feature/abc: 4fb4785 no good - test T1 failed
```

but the important point is that, since a stash entry takes for parent whichever commit HEAD points to when the entry is made :

`L` is the parent of `f1d6b3a` (let's call it `L'`)
`H` is the parent of `94722ae` (let's call it `H'`)
`F` is the parent of `4fb4785` (let's call it `F'`)

which, in the tree, could be pictured as

```
          F' <<< stash@{2}
         /
        F---G <<< feature/abc      H' <<< stash@{1}
       /                          / 
      /                          H---I <<< bugfix/123
     /                          /     \
A---B---C---D------------------E---F---J <<< master
         \
          \
           K---L---M <<< feature/xyz
                \
                 L' <<< stash@{0}
```

Then it's much easier to see that although they're listed sequentially in your `stash list`, they're in fact unrelated.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Basically if I do " git checkout -b branch-name " will do my work first I need to apply stash changes and perform above command right?

Comment: Ya, it's creating a new branch but the branch is locally present. Is there any way to create it as a remote branch which will reflect in my repo

Comment: I'm not too sure of what you mean here... if you need the new branch created from the stash to also exist remotely afterwards, set its upstream and push it to remote. But I might have missed your point... can you elaborate?