# Terminal should tell me if i have a stash for that branch

Tags: git, git-stash

I work on multiple branches together & sometimes I forget about that progress I made on another feature branch, and start from the beginning because I didn't check by asking the git stash list.

Is there a way that terminal will inform me about the stash on that branch whenever I checkout to new branch?

Comment: Minor but important point: stashes are not *on* branches. That's half the point of a stash, that it's not on *any* branch. (The message "WIP on branch..." means that when you made the stash, which isn't on a branch, you made it while *you* were on a branch.)

Answer (score 3):

The stash message *might* have the information, but stash entries are not specifically linked to branches (see a small demo of the fact [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56898959/1057485)). You might as well stash from *no branch at all*, for that matter.

So the short answer is **you can't**.

That being said, in many cases you'll have results with some grepping on your stash list :

```
git stash list | grep "your-branch"
```

Then again, this is not a given, it'll ultimately depend on your stash entries naming.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can define your own alias in `~/.gitconfig` which executes `git stash list` before `git checkout whatever`:

```
[alias]
  mycheckout = "!f() { git stash list; git checkout \"$1\"; }; f"
```

This way at least you can see the stash list every time. Maybe you can invert the two commands so the stash list is on the bottom, more visible.

Answer (score 0):

If you use bash completion (or other completions) set environment variable [`GIT_PS1_SHOWSTASHSTATE`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5b0ca878e008e82f91300091e793427205ce3544/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh#L44) to any non-empty value in your `~/.bash_profile`. If you have something stashed there will be `$` next to the branch name.